# Access of undefined property CONFIG::

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to build a Flex project with flash builder 4.6.  This project *should*  be fully functional because it has been built before,  however I am getting a lot of build errors involving "CONFIG"

The error:
"Access of undefined property LOGGING."

```
CONFIG::LOGGING
{
import org.osmf.logging.Logger;
}
```

To be honest I am a ActionScript noob,  so I am not sure what to call this snip of code.  Although it looks like a namespace or a struct I suspect its a configuration option.  How so I define this property LOGGING?  Why would it be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing a compiler argument that adds conditional compilation.  [Check out the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html).

Basically, you'll need to add something like this:

```
-define=CONFIG::LOGGING,true
```

to your compiler string.